# Python break statement details

Tags: python, break

Can anyone give me details about this problem, please ?

```
for i in range(1,10):
      if i == 5:
           break
      print("number is ", i)


Output:
number is 1
number is 2
number is 3
number is 4
```

My question is: why did not come 5 ?? I told here i == 5 that mean when i value is 5 then it should break and give result 5 .

```
now,  if i > 5:
         break
    print(i)
Output: 
     number is 1
     number is 2
     number is 3
     number is 4
     number is 5
```

here 5 > 5 it is not true . So what about it ??

And last thing if structure

```
for i in range(1,10):
print(i)
if i < 5:
    break

 Output: only 1
```

Question: the result should come at least 1 to 4 . but is not why ?

Thanks to all . Hope you can understand and give me a details of my questions.

Comment: It's because you `break` it before `print` statement

Comment: Right, but here is anther problem ,,, 

let, if i > 5: 
           break 

Now you will get number is 5 

that mean, it is going to wrong , because of 5 > 5 , false . 

what's about you think buddy ??

Comment: Can't you just read the instructional material that accompanies this assignment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: The OP isn't asking you the teach him anything nor it gaves any clue that it's an assignment. Though he could've done some extended research on his own. Since this is a very beginner question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for why it did not print 5 is because you brake the loop before it got to `print("number is ", i)`.

```
for i in range(1,10):
      if i == 5: #when i is 5 this will be true
           break #break the loop exits the loop
      #----------------------This is not run when i==5 because the loop already ended
      print("number is ", i)
```

if you wanted to print 5

```
for i in range(1,10):

     print("number is ", i) #put this in front
     if i == 5: #when i is 5 this will be true
           break #break the loop exits the loop
```

And as a side note: `range(1,10)` is actually `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and ten is not included since python skips the last one

**To OP's comment:**

```
for i in range(1,10):

     if i > 5: #when i is 5 this will be false, so the loop doesn't break
           break #break the loop when i > 5 (ie. 6) so now the print() isn't reached and will not print 6

     print("number is ", i) #since the loop didn't break when i is 5, it printed i
```

**For your other two new examples:**

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i > 5:
         break #exits here skips the print since it's after this
    print(i) #the print statement is here so when i > 5 this is not reached
#on the other hand:
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i) #the print statement is in front of the break statement so now it will print 6 too since the loop hasn't break yet
    if i > 5:
         break #exits here after the print()
#output also includes 6
```

And last thing if structure

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i) #only 1 got printed since the loop break before it get to 2
    if i < 5: #when i < 5 so it breaks in the first loop when i is 1
        break #exits the loop
```

*you might want to check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm)*  and see if it helps

Comment: Hmm, Thank you for your valuable comment, But I have another question .
if i > 5 :
   break 

print(i) 

Output: 1,2,3,4,5 

here is  5 > 5 . False . It is not true . why did I see this result ?? 
I am totally feeling mess :(

Comment: do the mind writing it in your original post as an edit? It's hard reading it in comments @VubonRoy

Comment: I edited my question . Any way thanks for your help :)

Comment: @VubonRoyI added two more examples for your question. Hope they clarified break for you

Answer (score 0):

On the i = 5 iteration, you pass the condition of your if test and execute the then block of your statement, which consists of break.  The break statement causes you to exit the loop.  The print statement is part of the loop body and is never reached on the iteration where i=5.